# KML to Postgis table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to save some KML files to PostgreSQL.
I'm using postgis and this is a sample of what I've done so far.

```
INSERT INTO police_crime_boundaries (name, polygon) VALUES (
    'A',
    ST_GeomFromKML('<LinearRing>
            <coordinates>-2.69927798816,52.9954289967,0 -2.70075298816,52.9932649967,0
                   </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>')
);
```

Anyone have any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Getting the data from here: https://data.police.uk/data/boundaries/

Comment: Do you get any error? What is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting an error: ERROR:  invalid KML representation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LinearRing` can not be stored to/retrieved from a `Geometry` column ([see the document)](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/LinearRing.html)

So you should either use `<Polygon>` tag instead of `<LinearRing>` or  wrap it with `OuterBoundary` and `Polygon` tags like below  :

```
<Polygon>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
```